# Why does one click event get mapped to 3 different values with 3 subscribers?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

With the code below, when I click the Refresh button, I see three different values being logged to the console. For example:

```
map 1541170826468
map 1541170826469 
map 1541170826470
```

I expected that one click event be mapped to one single value that is logged three times. Why do I see three different values logged?

Here is the code, also runnable at https://codepen.io/ssfjggv-kwidgf/pen/rQBoeX?editors=0010

```
var refreshButton = document.querySelector(".refresh");
var refreshClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(refreshButton, "click");

var requestStream = refreshClickStream
  .map(function() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  });

requestStream.subscribe(function(time) {
  console.log('map ' + time)
});

requestStream.subscribe(function(time) {
  console.log('map ' + time)
});

requestStream.subscribe(function(time) {
  console.log('map ' + time)
});
```

Comment: You make 3 subscriptions and thus call `console.log` 3 times.

Comment: @martin, yeah, but the logged time values are different: 1541170826468, 1541170826469 and 1541170826470. I expect one click event is mapped to one time value logged 3 times. Instead there are 3 different time values.

Comment: You can chain the `share()` operator after the  `map` operator which returns the timestamp

Comment: @Picci 's comment along with an explanation should be the answer.

Comment: Yep, after searching for some resources for `share`, I found that "A stream will run with each new subscription added to it." Unexpected, but OK... Thanks!